# Spacy Convert and Train UTF-8 Encoding CLI issues

Tags: encoding, utf-8, spacy

I am training a NER on a foreign language which has a lot of unicode items in there. I create a IOB file and use the cli spacy convert functionality to make it spacy compatible so I can train on that set. However the file is turned into a us-ascii file format. I saw a thread [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2337) talking about that Spacy automatically solves this, but how does this work on inference? I also couldn't find where Spacy loads in the data using ujson anymore.

So my question is, does Spacy handle this automatically? And how do I feed my text the best to the Spacy inference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escaped UTF-8 will be read in correctly by the library `srsly` (which is using a fork of `ujson` internally). If you're worried, you can double-check with `srsly.read_json("file.json")`. You provide python strings (python3 `str`) as input.